# skydrive direct link

Tags: embed, onedrive

I have a SWF on SkyDrive in public folder. How can I get the link to this file so that using  tag it will be directly rendered on the webpage.
I was unable to get such link that will allow to render the file. I tried Embed link. It showed the file icon instead of rendering. When clicked it redirected to the SkyDrive folder.

However I was able to do this on DropBox since it provides direct link to the file instead querying with resource id as in case of SkyDrive:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <embed src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/93470848/helloworld.swf" />
      <embed src="https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=B9A9203330B6DFFE&resid=B9A9203330B6DFFE%211085&authkey=AIRyW-raOQXH2-g" /> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution in the mean time?